# Creating iOS Plugin in Unity

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to Unity3d 3.5, and I've been reading over this manual for how to create iOS plugins in Unity (I'm using the pro version):
http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html

I'm under the impression that there is a script that will scan Plugins/iOS in Unity's project folder, and symlink everything in there into Xcode. The manual pretty much just scims over how to do it, and it is not very helpful for a beginner. I was wondering if there is just a single file floating around that will accomplish this, or if it is different for every app? Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Also, does anyone know if there is a way to have Unity include the .h files and plist's in the Plugins/iOS folder? That sounds like a much easier process.

Comment: Which version of Unity are you using?

Comment: @ThomasW Unity3d Pro, sorry I'll add that in.

Comment: No, the release version of Unity. 3.4? 3.5?

Comment: @ThomasW Oh I'm on version 3.5

Answer (score 3):

And also make sure that you define all your C# methods are of the format :

`[DllImport ("__Internal")]
private static extern float FooPluginFunction ();`

and your c functions should be wrapped inside

```
extern "C" {
  float FooPluginFunction ();
 }
```

If they are not, your app will break

Answer (score 2):

I just tried a quick test with Unity 3.5 and the feature to automatically include the native code in the `Assets/Plugins/iOS` folder appears to work, although it is limited. As the document mentions, subfolders are not supported. This feature works when you create your Xcode project by using the Unity "Build" command, no script is required.

There is a sample project linked to on that page, but it is not set up properly. The native code needs to be moved from `Assets/Code` to `Assets/Plugins/iOS`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah I've been using the built in feature to include the files in Assets/Plugins/iOS, but it doesn't include .h files, so the build in Xcode breaks. Is there any way to have Unity include the .h files in that folder? Or could I maybe drag and drop any of the files in that sample project into Unity? Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: When you use that mechanism it creates a symlink to the header file in the `Libraries` folder of the Xcode project. Check to see if that link is getting created. Also, are you using subfolders in the `Assets/Plugins/iOS` folder?

Comment: Note that Xcode doesn't have full support for these symlinks. It doesn't show the counterpart (e.g. header file) for files referred to through symlinks.

Comment: Cool thank you, that makes sense. I'm not using any subfolders, and when I try and drag and drop the .h file into the Xcode project, it states that it already exists like you mentioned. But, when it builds it cannot locate the file.

Comment: To find the header file Unity adds a path to the 'Libraries' folder to the "Library Search Paths" property of the "Unity-iPhone" target. Is that property in place? It should show in in the "Resolved" settings for the target.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy or modify the info.plist file you can do that using the new [PostProcessBuild] attribute.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PostProcessBuildAttribute.html

You can use that to copy an info.plist from a known location to your build directory, overwriting the existing one, or you can use something like [PlistCS](http://the.darktable.com/post/30467044618/proudly-parse-plists-in-unity3d-editor) to modify the existing info.plist.